# Eclipse java program run arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

I have written a program to traverse a directory and crawl for files of a certain extension i.e: c files, h files. I am trying to search for all files of c extension using "*.c" in the run arguments but that does not seem to work. What should it be instead? Any advise would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard expansions(*.c in your case) are handled by a shell such as bash or zsh. The expansions happen when you invoke the java command from a terminal or a shell script and the result is passed to your application. These wildcards will never be expanded if you are invoking you application using java program run arguments in eclipse. Consider using commons-io [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to handle wildcard expansions from your java code if you want expansions without using a shell.